# Angularjs checkbox not checked at start

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have a problem to make an angularjs checkbox checked.

the basket[0].Partdelivery come frome db with 1
update() make a post to the db

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1"  class="checkbox" ng-model="basket[0].PartDelivery" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-change="update()">
    {{basket[0].PartDelivery}}
</label>

<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1"  class="checkbox" ng-model="1" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-change="update()">
</label>
```

And I also tested this in the html:

```
<div ng-controller="basketController as bc" ng-init="basket={basket}; deliveryaddress={deliveryaddress}; getcheckboxes(basket[0].PartDelivery)">

<input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1"  class="checkbox" ng-model="partDeliveryCheck.value" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-change="update()">
```

in the controller:

```
$scope.getcheckboxes = function(PartDelivery){
    $scope.partDeliveryCheck={value: PartDelivery};
};
```

but the checkbox is not checked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ng-model` is a double-bind variable. You've passed in a `1` in your first example, which can't be a variable.

Try this

index.html

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.checked">
Is checked: {{vm.checked}}
```

Controller.js

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.checked = true;
});
```

Here's a plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/TywBTouaKuU8xHFNlQQU?p=preview

You can also take a look at the `ngChecked` directive https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

Comment: @Andreas Please accept the answer if this solved your problem.